# Cypress 12 Typescript: Using AWS Cognito Programically

Tags: typescript, cypress, aws-amplify

I've been stuck on the same issue for a few days now and can't seem to wrap my head around the issue, so I'm hoping someone smarter than me can point me in the right direction.

I'm trying to programically implement Cognito authentication into my Cypress 12 TypeScript project (I'm using v12.5) and I've tried following multiple reference materials including:

- [The guide Cypress provides on doing this](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/end-to-end-testing/amazon-cognito-authentication)
- [This guide which I saw referenced on another StackOverflow answer](https://medium.com/trans-it/use-cypress-to-test-aws-amplify-apps-with-authentication-c2dfcb8accab)
- [This guide which I saw elsewhere](https://aws.plainenglish.io/aws-amplify-cognito-login-and-component-testing-with-cypress-b44dc0ea9370)

I've defaulted back to the point I've literally copied their example into my code and I always end up with the same error when attempting to load the test via Cypress: **`Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null`**

Screenshot of what it looks like when trying to run within Cypress:
[image: Cypress Error]

This seems to be related to the import of Auth from aws-amplify, because as soon as I remove the import the code will often run and fail for lack of authentication.  From what I can tell from googling this message normally comes up when there's a circular reference but I've checked my files using madge and it's not flagging anything.

I've got a feeling the issue relates to the fact I have a TypeScript project and I'm having to globally declare the Cypress namespace for commands, along with importing the file in e2e.ts, but if I don't do this then Commands just don't seem to work at all and the whole implementation breaks.

Here's the stacktrace I'm getting when trying to run the test:

```
Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
   at ./node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-lex-runtime-service/dist-cjs/models/LexRuntimeServiceServiceException.js (webpack:///./node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-lex-runtime-service/dist-cjs/models/LexRuntimeServiceServiceException.js:5)
    at __webpack_require__ (webpack:///webpack/bootstrap:19)
    at ./node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-lex-runtime-service/dist-cjs/models/models_0.js (webpack:///./node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-lex-runtime-service/dist-cjs/models/models_0.js:5:44)
    at __webpack_require__ (webpack:///webpack/bootstrap:19)
    at ./node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-lex-runtime-service/dist-cjs/commands/DeleteSessionCommand.js (webpack:///./node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-lex-runtime-service/dist-cjs/commands/DeleteSessionCommand.js:6:19)
    at __webpack_require__ (webpack:///webpack/bootstrap:19)
    at ./node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-lex-runtime-service/dist-cjs/LexRuntimeService.js (webpack:///./node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-lex-runtime-service/dist-cjs/LexRuntimeService.js:4:31)
    at __webpack_require__ (webpack:///webpack/bootstrap:19)
    at ./node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-lex-runtime-service/dist-cjs/index.js (webpack:///./node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-lex-runtime-service/dist-cjs/index.js:5:21)
    at __webpack_require__ (webpack:///webpack/bootstrap:19)
From previous event:
    at evalScripts (http://localhost:54146/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:158798:58)
    at <unknown> (http://localhost:54146/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:158807:152)
From previous event:
    at runScriptsFromUrls (http://localhost:54146/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:158807:136)
    at Object.runScripts (http://localhost:54146/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:158821:12)
    at $Cypress.onSpecWindow (http://localhost:54146/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:147472:75)
```

Here's a summary of the code that is related to this issue:

**cypress/support/cognito.ts:**

```
import Amplify, { Auth } from 'aws-amplify'

Amplify.configure(Cypress.env('cognito.config'))

// Amazon Cognito
Cypress.Commands.add('loginByCognitoApi', (username: string, password: string) => {
  const log = Cypress.log({
    displayName: 'COGNITO LOGIN',
    message: [` Authenticating | ${username}`],
    // @ts-ignore
    autoEnd: false,
  })

  log.snapshot('before')

  const signIn = Auth.signIn({ username, password })

  cy.wrap(signIn, { log: false }).then((cognitoResponse: any) => {
    const keyPrefixWithUsername = `${cognitoResponse.keyPrefix}.${cognitoResponse.username}`

    window.localStorage.setItem(
      `${keyPrefixWithUsername}.idToken`,
      cognitoResponse.signInUserSession.idToken.jwtToken
    )

    window.localStorage.setItem(
      `${keyPrefixWithUsername}.accessToken`,
      cognitoResponse.signInUserSession.accessToken.jwtToken
    )

    window.localStorage.setItem(
      `${keyPrefixWithUsername}.refreshToken`,
      cognitoResponse.signInUserSession.refreshToken.token
    )

    window.localStorage.setItem(
      `${keyPrefixWithUsername}.clockDrift`,
      cognitoResponse.signInUserSession.clockDrift
    )

    window.localStorage.setItem(
      `${cognitoResponse.keyPrefix}.LastAuthUser`,
      cognitoResponse.username
    )

    window.localStorage.setItem('amplify-authenticator-authState', 'signedIn')
    log.snapshot('after')
    log.end()
  })

  cy.visit('https://myurl.com/login')
})
```

**cypress/support/index.ts (using [this logic](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/typescript-support#Types-for-Custom-Commands))**:

```
export {}

declare global {
    namespace Cypress {    
        interface Chainable<Subject = any> {
            loginAs(role: string): Chainable<JQuery<HTMLElement>>; // Unrelated command
            clickMenuLink(linkText: string): Chainable<JQuery<HTMLElement>>;  // Unrelated command
            loginByCognitoApi(username: string, password: string): Chainable<JQuery<HTMLElement>>;
        }
    }
}
```

**cypress/support/e2e.ts:**

```
import './commands' // Nothing in here that impacts this issue
import './cognito'
```

I've tried:

- Import `'./index'` via e2e.ts instead, hoping that would pull through the delared interface methods and also tried removing `'./cognito.ts'`.  Cypress can't see the command anymore so says it doesn't exist.
- Tried just switching the cognito file to a standard JS file but I think for that to work effectively I'd have to switch my whole project away from TypeScript.
- Remove the loginByCognitoApi interface from the Cypress chainable, it's also not recognised as a command at that point either.
- Different implementations of essentially the same logic - all seem to result in the same outcome.

Any guidance on this error message would be appreciated!

Comment: If this is actually possible (which I'm sure it is) I've not cracked it yet - switching back to a JavaScript Cypress project doesn't encounter this error so it's something TypeScript related at least.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon the exact same error.

My problem was related to setting the following resolution (using Yarn Berry):
`yarn set resolution --save @aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity@npm:3.6.1 ^3.267.0`, a big unsafe jump.

I was trying to avoid adding a transitive dependency on `react-native`, which for some reason was part of `@aws-sdk/middleware-retry`.

In the end,

- I changed my dependency to `"@aws-amplify/auth": "^5.1.8"` and import to `import { Auth } from '@aws-amplify/auth'`.
- cleared node_modules and yarn.lock (to remove previously set resolutions)
- not related, but also ran `yarn set resolution --save @aws-sdk/middleware-retry@npm:3.6.1 3.267.0`, to get rid of `react-native`.

I hope this helps!